# PHP 7 and 5.6 parallel in Nginx

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, php7

I want to use PHP 7 with newer apps and PHP 5.6 with apps, that doesn't work with PHP 7. So I try to configure Nginx to enable different PHP versions for different pathes. But it doesn't work:

```
 # should enable PHP5 for all PHP-scripts under /vexim/ path
 location ^~ /vexim/.*\.php$ {
     include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
     fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
 }
```

And the default for anything else should be PHP 7:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}
```

With this configuration PHP scripts under /vexim/ are not parsed at all.
How to get this working with different pathes and PHP versions?

(Using Debian 8.3 Jessie, Nginx 1.8.1 (dotdeb), PHP 5.6, PHP 7 (dotdeb))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`location ^~` is not a regex location, it is a prefix location that takes precedence over all regex locations.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

What you probably want is:

```
location ~ ^/vexim/.*\.php$ { ... }
location ~ \.php$ { ... }
```

Make sure that the `/vexim` location comes first as regex locations are ordered.